# Powershell - Catch block does not invoke even there an error occurs

Tags: powershell

Why powershell does not fall to catch statement even there are errors generated ? In this case I purposely remove Data folder to see whether catch block will be invoked or not.

```
Catch
{
$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
$FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
Send-MailMessage -From xxxxxxxxxx
Break
}
```

This errors message received from powershell

```
Set-Content : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Data\CUST.csv'.
At D:\Data\Scripts\CUST_HOUSEKEPPING.ps1:55 char:79
+ $getData2 | Where-Object{[regex]::matches($_,"\,").count -eq 22} | set-content <<<<  $outPath
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Data\CUST.csv:String) [Set-Content], DirectoryNotFo
 undException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterDirectoryNotFoundError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the calls in PowerShell where `-ErrorAction` determines how your code responds.

Use this sample code with and without the "-ErrorAction Stop" part and see the difference. Without, it behaves like your question.  With, it throws exception.

```
try
{
    "FOO" | Set-Content -Path 'd:\doesnotexist\file1.txt' -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Caught something..."
}
finally
{
    Write-Output "Performing finally..."
}
```

Also see [about_CommonParameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847884.aspx)

Comment: `-ErrorAction Stop` is required because the error is non-terminating (the pipeline can continue working). Try/catch only catches terminating errors that would normally have stopped the script/function from continuing.